# for-each xsltree not on the same level node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml tree:

```
<cashflows>
  <interestFlows>
    <interestPaymentPeriod>
        <calculationPeriod>
          <startDate>20230102</startDate>
          <endDate>20230130</endDate> 
        </calculationPeriod>
    </interestPaymentPeriod>
    <interestPaymentPeriod>
        <calculationPeriod>
          <startDate>20230202</startDate>
          <endDate>20230228</endDate> 
        </calculationPeriod>
    </interestPaymentPeriod>
    <interestPaymentPeriod>
        <calculationPeriod>
          <startDate>20230301</startDate>
          <endDate>20230330</endDate> 
        </calculationPeriod>
    </interestPaymentPeriod>
  </interestFlows>
  <capitalFlows>
    <flow>
       <flowSubType>AMO<flowSubType>
       <date>20230116<date>
    </flow>
    <flow>
       <flowSubType>AMO<flowSubType>
       <date>20230116<date>
    </flow> 
    <flow>
       <flowSubType>INT<flowSubType>
       <date>20230116<date>
    </flow>
  </capitalFlows>
</cashflows>
```

For each flow[flowSubType = 'AMO'] then divide the corresponding section of InterestpaymentPeriod/calculationPeriod into two blocks.
If the AMO date falls inside an interestpayment period then divide its corresponding calculation period into two block like:
[startDate ; AMO date] and [AMO date ; endDate].

The desired output would be:

```
<cashflows>
  <interestFlows>
    <interestPaymentPeriod>
        <calculationPeriod>
          <startDate>20230102</startDate>
          <endDate>20230116</endDate> 
        </calculationPeriod>
        <calculationPeriod>
          <startDate>20230116</startDate>
          <endDate>20230130</endDate> 
        </calculationPeriod>
    </interestPaymentPeriod>
    <interestPaymentPeriod>
        <calculationPeriod>
          <startDate>20230202</startDate>
          <endDate>20230220</endDate> 
        </calculationPeriod>
        <calculationPeriod>
          <startDate>20230220</startDate>
          <endDate>20230228</endDate> 
        </calculationPeriod>
    </interestPaymentPeriod>
    <interestPaymentPeriod>
        <calculationPeriod>
          <startDate>20230301</startDate>
          <endDate>20230330</endDate> 
        </calculationPeriod>
    </interestPaymentPeriod>
  </interestFlows>
  <capitalFlows>
    <flow>
       <flowSubType>AMO<flowSubType>
       <date>20230116<date>
    </flow>
    <flow>
       <flowSubType>AMO<flowSubType>
       <date>20230220<date>
    </flow> 
    <flow>
       <flowSubType>INT<flowSubType>
       <date>20230116<date>
    </flow>
  </capitalFlows>
</cashflows>
```

I have tried the followwing:

```
 <xsl:template match="interestPaymentPeriod/calculationPeriod">

      
       
        <xsl:variable name="found" select="'false'"></xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="0"></xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:variable name="amortizingDate" select="''"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="0"></xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:variable name="path" select="../../../capitalFlows/flow" />
        
        
       <xsl:for-each select="$path">
                 <xsl:variable name="pos" select="$pos + 1"></xsl:variable>
              
          <xsl:if test="calculationStartDate &lt; (../../../capitalFlows/flow[position()=$pos and flowSubType = 'AMO']/exdividendDate) and (../../../capitalFlows/flow[position()=$pos and flowSubType = 'AMO']/exdividendDate) &lt; calculationEndDate ">
            <xsl:variable name="found" select="'true'"></xsl:variable> 
            <xsl:variable name="position" select="$pos"></xsl:variable> 
            
          </xsl:if>
          
          <xsl:if test="calculationStartDate &lt; (../../../capitalFlows/flow[flowSubType = 'AMO']/exdividendDate) and (../../../capitalFlows/flow[flowSubType = 'AMO']/exdividendDate) &lt; calculationEndDate ">    
             <xsl:variable name="found" select="'false'"></xsl:variable>    
          </xsl:if> 
             
     </xsl:for-each>



.....
```

But it seems that the section for-each select="../../../capitalflows/flow" does not seem to work as it did not even go inside the loop at all.
For info, the variable $path returns 3 (the total number of flow/ nodes) which is correct. So the path is correct. But somehow passing it through a for-each loop does not behave as expected as I am never getting inside the loop.

Any idea please ?

Comment: Your XML seems to be invalid to begin with, e.g. line 2: `<interestFlows>` is never being closed.

Comment: I just tapped it manually.. I have corrected it. @white

Comment: "For each flow[flowSubType = 'AMO'] then divide the relevant InterestpaymentPeriod/calculationPeriod into two blocks.": how is "relevant" determined, based on the date? But your samples seem odd, the input has two `<flowSubType>AMO<flowSubType>` with the same date `<date>20230116<date>` while somehow your output has two AMO with different dates. Please explain in more details how these dates are computed/generated.

Comment: If the AMO date falls inside an interest payment period then divide its corresponding calculation period into two block [startDate;AMO date] and [AMO date; endDate].

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="calculationPeriod">
    <xsl:variable name="amo" select="/cashflows/capitalFlows/flow[flowSubType='AMO'][current()/startDate le date and date le current()/endDate]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$amo">
            <calculationPeriod>
                <xsl:copy-of select="startDate"/>
                <endDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$amo/date"/>
                </endDate> 
            </calculationPeriod>
            <calculationPeriod>
                <startDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$amo/date"/>
                </startDate> 
                <xsl:copy-of select="endDate"/>
            </calculationPeriod>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result in your example is different from what you show (even after fixing your input to be a well-formed XML).

Note that this assumes that for each `calculationPeriod` there can be at most one `flow` with intersecting `date`.

Comment: Hi, I did not understand this part : current()/startDate le date and date le current()/endDate ?

Comment: See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-function

Comment: Actually, I know what current() means. but why did you wrote "le date and le" just after ? I have never seen that ??
Also, amo variable should start with ../../../ as you are inside of calculationPeriod. Otherwise, it will not work. To end, I cannot see the for each looop here.

Comment: It tests for the condition of `startDate ≤ date ≤ endDate`. The variable is using an absolute path, starting from the root. There is no `for-each` here and none is required. And it does work, at least the way I understood you want it to work.

Comment: I have just tested it and I confirm it does not work :(
I have also added ../../../ to the amo variable and does not change :( 
<xsl:variable name="amo" select="../../../cashflows/capitalFlows/flow[flowSubType='AMO'][current()/startDate le date and date le current()/endDate]" />

It always go to the otherwise..

Comment: Does this work the way you would expect?  https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUWwaH

Comment: Indeed, it works on the link you have sent to me.
But on my side when I try to make it work it does not work :(

Maybe because of the path of amo ?
I have reduced it in my sample from xml/securityHeaders/securityHeader/securities/security/financialDefinition/bondDefinition/streams/stream/cashflows/capitalFlows/flow to /cashflows/capitalFlows/flow ?

I have added the whole path but it does not work. I always go to the otherwise..

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to help you with a problem I cannot reproduce.